# When running mvn test -Dtest=.. File can't be found

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, citrus-framework

I have a citrusframework test, which when run with

```
mvn verify
```

it is able to find a json template file which is required to run the test, but when run with

```
mvn test -Dtest=SampleXmlIT#saveGroupTrips
```

suddenly it throws me following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/templates/json/api/config/saveGroupTrips.json (No such file or directory)
```

my folder structure is as follows:

```
citrus-scada
|-src
| |-main
| |-test
|   |-java 
|   | |- com : *.java testclasses
|   |
|   |-resources
|   | |-com : xml-files which describes the testcases and reference the files required
|   |
|   |-templates : referenced files
|-target
```

does the working directory change?

Comment: Put your files into src/test/resouces and read them via class.getResourceAsStream("/...")..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

src/test/templates is no [Maven Standard Directory](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) so there must exist some configuration which adds it to the classpath for test.

Because your test is named SampleXmlIT (IT is the important part, see [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) why) the test is executed with [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) in phase integration-test when you execute `mvn verify`

Now you call `mvn test -Dtest=SampleXmlIT#saveGroupTrips` but now it is executed with [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).

If you want to execute tests isolated with maven-failsafe-plugin try:

`mvn verify -Dit.test=SampleXmlIT#saveGroupTrips`

See also [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I didnt know what to look for before.